# php group multidimentional array by word

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, group-by

I have this kind of array written on PHP.

```
$array[] = ["name"=>"KIT", "v1"=>"val1", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val3"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"BAT", "v1"=>"val1", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val3"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"ISL", "v1"=>"val1", "v2"=>"val1", "v3"=>"val1"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"KIT", "v1"=>"val4", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val2"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"BAT", "v1"=>"val1", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val1"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"ENS", "v1"=>"val1", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val3"]; 
$array[] = ["name"=>"ENS", "v1"=>"val3", "v2"=>"val2", "v3"=>"val1"];
```

I wanted to group them so the output would be

```
BAT val1 val2 val3
    val1 val2 val1
ENS val1 val2 val3
    val3 val2 val1
ISL val1 val1 val1
KIT val1 val2 val3
    val4 val2 val2
```

I tried to `ksort()` but not working:

```
$group_arr = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $group_arr[$value["name"]][$key] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: Did my post helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $v = $value;
    unset($v['name']);
    $group_arr[$value["name"]][] = $v;
}
```

No use of `ksort` is needed. Notice the keys of `$array` are just integer and you don't need them in the result array

Comment: This includes "name" in each subarray. https://3v4l.org/02dD9 . And is pretty much the same as OPs result. It's only the key names that is different https://3v4l.org/6PSri

Comment: The idea was to group the result by the name. I agree about the name in the `$value` - edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a nested loop.
In order to not add the name in the new array I extract it and use array_slice to not get it in the nested foreach.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $name = $value["name"];
    foreach(array_slice($value,1) as $val){
        $group_arr[$name][] = $val;
    }
}
var_dump($group_arr);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["KIT"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "val3"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "val4"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "val2"
  }
  ["BAT"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "val3"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "val1"
  }
  ["ISL"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "val1"
  }
  ["ENS"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "val1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "val3"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "val3"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "val2"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "val1"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ebuFt